# Random Facebook pixel error messages

Tags: wordpress, conflict, facebook-pixel

For the past few weeks I've noticed that in a client's website WordPress dashboard, when I click on the Search box, I get a huge mess of error messages popping up across the screen. The error messages all start with "Error: Multiple pixels with conflicting versions were detected on this page." When I google this error message I get lots of discussion about something called "Facebook Pixel," but to my knowledge there is no such thing installed on this site. I see nothing of the sort in the Plugins page and the vast majority of changes to this site (other than creating posts) is done by me, and I have never heard of Facebook Pixel until this came up. I imagine it might be some plugin conflict, but as I said, no one to my knowledge knowingly installed Facebook Pixel. I don't know where to look to straighten this out. The site performance seems to be unaffected, but clearly something is out of whack in the back end.

I had a screenshot ready, but I apparently need a "reputation" of 10 to add it to the post, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

"Facebook Pixel" is a snippet of code that looks like this:

```
<script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
  _fbq.push(['addPixelId', "1234567890"]);
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(["track", "PixelInitialized", {}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1234567890&amp;ev=NoScript" /></noscript>
```

It's not necessarily added by a plugin. Check to make sure whether or not it's been added into any "Header Scripts" sections of your website (or even "Footer Scripts" or "Body Scripts"). There may be a "custom scripts" plugin in your site, or they were added directly in a theme or plugin file.

I believe these errors can also be triggered by iframes - so if you have any embeds or iframes on your site, make sure they aren't the ones that have the pixel errors.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this or something similar as well. Perhaps this will solve your problem.

The form auto fill settings in chrome were causing this error. More Tools >> Clear browsing data... >> Check "Autofill form data" For some reason this was populating a Error: Multiple pixels with conflicting versions were detected on this page error in the search auto complete.